# How to change colors in react charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I'm making a chart and im kind of confused. ill attach a photo below [image]

So first off, I want the title to not be undefined, how do I change the title? And I want to change the background color of the chart below the lines, heres my code

```
{data?.length > 0 && (
            <Line
            
            options={options}
           height={"300%"}
           
            
            data={{
                datasets: [
                    {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(204, 16, 52, 0.5)",
                    borderColor: "#CC1034",
                    data: data,
                    
                }
            ]
                
            }}
            
            />  
        )}
```

Comment: to add the title, add a `label` property to your dataset --> `datasets: [{label: 'title', backgroundColor: "rgba(...`

Answer (score 0):

The legend label will be correctly displayed if you define `label` on your `dataset`, this was mentioned by [WhiteHat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5090771/whitehat) in his comment.

In order to obtain the background color below the lines (basically an area chart), you need to add [`fill: true`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling) to the `dataset`.

To make it work, you also need to import and register `Filler` from `chart.js`.

Please take a look at this [**Code Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-monad-sl7wpi?file=/App.tsx) and see how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I added styled to my chart:

```js
function MyChart({}) {
  const { data } = useChartConfig({
    height: 200,
    grouping: "primary",
    dataType: "ordinal",
  });

  const getSeriesStyle = React.useCallback((series) => {
    // Based off my chart bars
    const colorPalette = {
      series1: "#354657",
      series2: "#5597e2",
      series3: "#28A96C",
      series4: "#d44401",
      series5: "#ffe65b",
      series6: "#ffab1b",
    };

    return {
      fill: colorPalette[series.label],
    };
  }, []);

  return <Chart data={data} getSeriesStyle={getSeriesStyle} />;
}
```

Comment: it looks like you have a bar chart here thought and I have a line chart, correct me if im wrong though.